# I have an array of json object and I cant pop an element javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Good day guys, I have an **array of json** in the first part of the program it would look like this:

```
var jsonToSaveToDB = [
        {
            ProductID: null,
            Quantity: null,
            TotalPrice: null
        }
    ];
```

Later on the program, I have a function that will populate that array with json and as a result, it would look like this:

```
var jsonToSaveToDB = [

  {
        ProductID: 1,
        Quantity: 4,
        TotalPrice: 12.80
    },
    {
        ProductID: 2,
        Quantity: 2,
        TotalPrice: 12.80
    },

    ..... other elements of the array

    {
        ProductID: null,
        Quantity: null,
        TotalPrice: null
    }
];
```

and I want to popup the last element of the array.Because, All the value of that last element was null.

But the catch is, I can't pop an element from that array. If you want to see my code structure.

It would look like this:

```
<script>
var jsonToSaveToDB = [
    {
        ProductID: null,
        Quantity: null,
        TotalPrice: null
    }
];

///some codes....
//....
$(document).ready(function(){

   function checkoutNow() {

        $.each(carted_prods, function (index, element) {
            var newObj = {
                ProductID: parseInt(element.itemID),
                Quantity: parseInt(element.itemQuantity),
                TotalPrice: parseFloat(element.itemPrice)
            };
            jsonToSaveToDB.unshift(newObj);
        });

        console.log(jsonToSaveToDB);

        if (jsonToSaveToDB.length > 0) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/POS/POS/CheckoutProducts',
                data: { json: JSON.stringify(jsonToSaveToDB) },
                contentType: "application/json",
                success: function (result) {
                    console.log(result);
                }
            });
        }


        //console.log("Checkout now.");
    }

});

</script>
```

Comment: jsonToSaveToDB.pop() should work in you case. Please let me know what issue you are facing while using this.

Comment: the element is still there

Comment: I would suggest to create a https://stackblitz.com/ and put you code here, so we can figure out what is the issue with your code.

Comment: i have an NaN error I guess it was the carted_prods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already found an answer to my questions, the `carted_prods` variable was an array of json it contains an element with a `null` value which by the time that it goes to the `$.each()` it will populate a `NaN` so i use this code to filter out the element that doesn't have a `null` and `NaN`

```
 jsonToSaveToDB = jsonToSaveToDB.filter(obj => !isNaN(obj.ProductID));
 jsonToSaveToDB = jsonToSaveToDB.filter(obj => obj.ProductID != null)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the issue that you're facing in `jsonToSaveToDB` array is that you're always getting null values for `ProductID, Quantity, TotalPrice` in the last element of the array, you can easily remove them using `jsonToSaveToDB.pop()`.

If you don't know where the position of the object element in the array `jsonToSaveToDB`, then you can filter them out from the array.

`jsonToSaveToDB.filter(obj => obj.ProductID !== null)`

I hope this helps. Let me know if you have any doubts.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not to initialise the array of object properties with null values at the beginning. Set initially

```js
var jsonToSaveToDB =[]
```

and

```js
function checkoutNow() {
    $.each(carted_prods, function (index, element) {
        if(element.itemID || element.itemQuantity || element.itemPrice){
            var newObj = {
                ProductID: parseInt(element.itemID),
                Quantity: parseInt(element.itemQuantity),
                TotalPrice: parseFloat(element.itemPrice)
            };
            jsonToSaveToDB.unshift(newObj);
        }
   });
   ... Other codes
}
```

This code will add the contents in the array without the null object value. And add a check in the `$.each` loop

```js
(if(element.itemID || element.itemQuantity || element.itemPrice))
```

That if any one value is present in the element, add it to the array. You can customise further according to the needs.Hope this helps.